# Missing control sequence inserted \def*

Tags: errors

I download a new package (Alegreya). But it gave an error *Missing control sequence inserted \def*.
How can i fix it.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Alegreya} %% Option 'black' gives heavier bold face 
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\AlegreyaOsF #1}}

\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

Comment: When you say you "downloaded a new package", did you follow the instructions in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1) That is, run `texhash`?

Comment: if you say "refresh FNDB", i did it. But the problem still exist.

Comment: I get no error. Can you add the relevant portion of the `.log` file?

Comment: i don't know about files so much. i downloaded it automatically from http://mirror.bjtu.edu.cn/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/

Comment: No error with pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX) (format=pdflatex 2014.1.17)

Comment: The bug is in package `Alegrya` in version 2014/01/10, if LuaTeX or XeTeX are not used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version 2014/01/10 of package [`Alegreya`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/alegreya) contained a typo, the star after `\def` in line 233 is not correct (probably a mix-up with the syntax for `\newcommand`).

Version 2014/01/14 has fixed the issue. It takes some time until the TeX distributions are updated.

Comment: `Alegreya` comes with more than a package file (fonts, ...). [alegreya.tds.zip](http://mirror.ctan.org/install/fonts/alegreya.tds.zip) might help for manual installations. Also map files might need to be updated. Perhaps it is easier to wait until MiKTeX has updated the package. I could not reproduce the new problem with an updated TeX Live.